# Javascript Loop - 2nd variable Not Displaying

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

Here is the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var offender_locations = [
    ["10010", "xxxxx", 3],
    ["10001", "xxxxx", 2],
    ["10002", "zzzzz", 1]
  ];
  for (i = 0; i < offender_locations.length; i++) {
    var address = offender_locations[i][0];
    var icon_img = offender_locations[i][1];
  }
</script>
```

**This is the output:**

1) 10010 - zzzzz
2) 10001 - zzzzz
3) 10002 - zzzzz

AS you can see *var address* outputs the correct value, but *var icon_img* does always repeat the same value.

I am a Javascript beginner and I have tried all ways I can think of but I still get the same results.

P.S. I have pasted the full script here :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var offender_locations = [
    ["10010", "offender_icon.png", 3],
    ["10001", "offender_icon.png", 2],
    ["10002", "visitor_icon.png", 1]
  ];
  var myOptions = {
    zoom: 10,
    center: latlng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), myOptions);
  var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0);

  for (i = 0; i < offender_locations.length; i++) {
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    var geocoder_map = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var address = offender_locations[i][0];
    var icon_img = offender_locations[i][1];
    geocoder_map.geocode({
      'address': address
    }, function (results, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          map: map,
          position: map.getCenter(),
          icon: icon_img
        });
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function (marker, i) {
          return function () {
            infowindow.setContent(offender_locations[i][0]);
            infowindow.open(map, marker);
          }
        })(marker, i));
      } else {
        alert("The requested offender is not mappable !")
      };
    });
  }
</script>
```

The markers in this script are all @ the correct postal code, but they all show the same icon (visitor_icon.png) !

Comment: it works for me ... please show me your output. Try poping the values out with simple alert box.

Comment: Are you sure? For me it doesn't do that and works as expected: http://jsfiddle.net/QpwGe/

Comment: It works for me as well in Firefox, where are you printing in above code?

Comment: I have just tesed the code alone and it works indeed. however, in my full code, the script doesnt work. I guess the problem must be somewhere else. I have included the full script in my post above! Thanks guys!

Comment: Check this out.. Working fine: http://jsfiddle.net/EjW9C/

Comment: @Bazzz the script at your url works for me as expected!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that you are creating a function in a loop. JavaScript has only function scope, not block scope. I.e. variables you create in a loop exist only once in the whole function, just the values changes per iteration.

At the time `icon_img` is evaluated (in the callback passed to `geocode`), the outer for loop already finished and `icon_img` has the value of the last iteration. It works for `address` because it is evaluated inside the loop, not later.

You have to 'capture' the current value of `icon_img` and you can do so by using an immediate function:

```
for (i = 0; i < offender_locations.length; i++) { 
    var infowindow   = new google.maps.InfoWindow(),
        geocoder_map = new google.maps.Geocoder(),
        address      = offender_locations[i][0],
        icon_img     = offender_locations[i][1];

    (function(addr, img) {  // <-- immediate function call
        geocoder_map.geocode({'address': addr}, function(results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    map: map,
                    position: map.getCenter(),
                    icon: img
                });
                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                    infowindow.setContent(addr);
                    infowindow.open(map, marker);
                });
            } else {
                alert("The requested offender is not mappable !");
            }
        });
    }(address, icon_img)); // <-- immediate function call
}
```

Maybe you hav to do this for even more variables... not sure.

Comment: To clarify (since the OP is a JS noob): when you create a function, it captures a *reference* to all of the variables that are in scope at the time the function is created.

In the original code, even though you're creating a new callback function for each iteration in your loop, they all reference the same value held by icon_img which, by the time those callbacks get invoked, ends up being whatever the last value it was set to ('zzzzz').

Comment: Thank You Felix and broofa! I am gonna change the code and let you guys know if i succeed :) But there shouldnt be a problem now!

Comment: @user668190: It made some further changes. E.g. I don't think that you need an immediate function when assigning the `click` handler. But try it...

Comment: Hi Felix, I have just copied your code into mine and it works fantastic for the moment! I will now take a look at it again and look for some improvements in whole script. Thanks again for your time!

Comment: One more thing, if you dont mind.. :) I am not sure, but just in case you know the Google maps api well: is there a simple way to modify it and set the center to a fixed marker?

Comment: @user668190: If I understand you correctly, you can do `map.setCenter(marker.getPosition())`. Is this what you mean? If not, what do you with *fixed* marker?

Comment: Thats exactly what I am trying to do, but I would like to have a specific marker (in example "marker1") as center. And the best thing would be to leave the option open to change the center afterwards (but thats another topic).

Comment: @user668190: Well you can always choose the marker you want ;)

Comment: Hi Felix, I have just realised this and that it seems to use the last marker by default, what is fine too. Thanks again for the help and excuse my poor english :/